# Unity3D go down on slopes with a animated character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developping a **3D game Unity** with a **squirrel** as the player.

I'm struggling with a problem of **slopes**. I know, there are a bunch of tutorial to go down a slope whithout 'floating in the air while walking' but I didn't find a fine solution. I think it's because of the **horizontal animations** of the squirrel (maybe). I have tried with addForce, with a modified speed, with gravity... (maybe I implemented it wrong). I know I can check if I'm in the air or not with *CharacterController.isGrounded* but I can't force the squirrel to stick on the slope while running or walking. I'm sorry by advance if my question is too vague or simple.

[image: Unity stuff for the squirrel]

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;


public class Squirrel : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator squirrel;
    public float gravity = 1.0f;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    float axisH, axisV;

    public static int munitions = 0;

    Rigidbody rb;

    [SerializeField]
    float walkSpeed = 2f, runSpeed = 8f, rotSpeed = 100f, jumpForce = 350;

    private bool isJumpKeyDown = false;
    [SerializeField] bool isJumping = false;

    Animator characterAnimator;

    int JumpCount = 0;
    public int MaxJumps = 1; //Maximum amount of jumps (i.e. 2 for double jumps)

    [SerializeField] GameObject nb_munitions;

    CharacterController characterController;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        munitions = 0;
        squirrel = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>();
        characterAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        JumpCount = MaxJumps;
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        GetInput();
        nb_munitions.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Glands : " + munitions; //Affichage du score
        Move();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isJumpKeyDown)
        {
            squirrel.SetTrigger("jump");
            JumpCount -= 1;
            isJumpKeyDown = false;
        }
    }
    public void GetInput()
    {
        axisV = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        axisH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            //On the ground
        }
        else
        {
            //on the air
        }


        if (axisV > 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            {
                transform.position += Vector3.forward * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                squirrel.SetBool("walk", true);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position += Vector3.forward * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

                squirrel.SetFloat("run", axisV);
                squirrel.SetBool("walk", false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            squirrel.SetFloat("run", 0);
        }

        if (axisH != 0 && axisV == 0)
        {
            squirrel.SetFloat("h", axisH);
        }
        else
        {
            squirrel.SetFloat("h", 0);
        }

        if (axisH != 0)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime * axisH);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (JumpCount > 0)
            {
                isJumpKeyDown = true;
            }
        }

        //Call munitions
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            if (Squirrel.munitions > 0)
            {
                SpawnerScript.Instance.NewSpawnRequest();
                munitions--;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does the player float when going down?

Comment: @HasnainShaukat when my character is at the top of a climb and I want to go down it, my character starts walking in the void at the same height as the point on the climb.

Comment: You need to check length of raycast checking ground. And see if the walk animation makes it root ?

Comment: characterController is working : I can see if i'm in the air or not but the walk animation stay 'straight' and I'm juste walking in the air at the same height of the climb. Maybe I can just point the forward vector 'down' to make the character run towards the ground

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the angle of the slope and make it the pitch for the mesh of the squirrel.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. My C# script "overwrited" the CharacterController and did not allow the squirrel to go down the slopes. Make sure you follow a move script that "respects" the CharacterController (if you pick one or you'll be fighting windmills).